# Expand array of 1 element every loop C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers, realloc

I have to let the user how many inputs he wants and every loop I need to expand the array to let others input, when `n=-1` I need to end the loop.

This is my code:

```
void extend(int *a)
{
    int *pt;
    pt = (int*) realloc(a , sizeof(int));   
}

int main()
{
    int *a;
    a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int i=0;
    int n=0;

    while(n!=-1) {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n != -1) {
            a[i] = n;
            extend(a);
            i++;        
        }
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

It works with 3 values then it stops working, I can loop as I want but when `n` become `-1` it crashes. I have an "invalid next size" error in some compiler.

**EDIT:**

This code works:

```
int main()
{
    int *a = (int*)malloc(0);
    int i=0;
    int n;

    do {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n!=-1) {
            i++;
            a = (int*) realloc(a , i*sizeof(int));
            a[i-1] = n;   
        }
    } while(n!=-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: good grief, indent your code!

Comment: never cast the return of *alloc, always check the return of *alloc

Comment: also you seem to think that the size passed to realloc is the increase, but it is not, it is the total size you want, so your realloc never grows anything, which, of course, would only be useful if you used the result of realloc

Comment: malloc(sizeof(int)) this will allocate only one int, the same for the realloc

Comment: You should start with something like malloc(n*sizeof(int)) and then when the number of elements are more then n, say m call realloc(m*sizeof(int))

Comment: @terencehill I start with 1 element and every time I add 1 element I need to expand by 1, I don't have to suppose how many elements user will give

Comment: you will not suppose. simply you start with a reasonable size. Realloc every time is not a good choice

Comment: I believe he is suggesting that having some "slack" in your array is more efficient that doing a realloc every time (so maybe start your array at size 16 and when you go to add the 17th element you grow it to 32 elements.  You just need to keep 2 sizes (the size of the array and the actual number used)

Comment: @JohnHascall Yes, and also realloc another 16 or what you think is a good choice for your problem but not one element every time

Comment: It's a good practice to use free() at the end of the program to "free" the memory allocated by malloc and realloc.

Comment: Consider quadratic growth of your array: 1, 2, 4, 8, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most imporant mistake is that you don't reassign the new `realloc()`ed pointer to the previous pointer and also you are not really changing the size.

Try this

```
size_t extend(int **original, size_t oldsize)
{
    void *pointer;
    pointer = realloc(*original, (oldsize + 1) * sizeof(*original);
    if (poitner == NULL)
        return oldsize;
    *original = pointer;
    return oldsize + 1;
}
```

and then in `main()`

```
size_t size;
int *data;
int number;

data = malloc(sizeof(int));
if (data == NULL)
    return -1;
size = 1;
while ((scanf("%d", &number) == 1) && (number != -1))
{
    data[size] = number;
    size = extend(data, size);
}
```

Also note,

1. Allocating memory is expensive in terms of CPU usage, so you might want to avoid doing it for every element. Perhaps define a `struct` to hold a size and a capacity (*an estimate of how many integers might be there*) and when the capacity is exceeded then `realloc()` to account for that allocating enough space to prevent `realloc()`ing again too quickly.
2. ALWAYS check the return value of `scanf()` or you will end up invoking undefined behavior and your program will behave in an undefined manner.

Comment: I would suggest to not realloc for every element

Comment: @terencehill Me too, but just answering the question and pointing out the mistake.

Comment: So it works sometimes because sometimes the realloc() extends the space previously allocated and it doesn't work other times because sometimes realloc returns a completely new starting address, and the code does not capture that new address.

Comment: Yes, `realloc()` can use the same address passed to it but not always.